# Stitch - Mongodb SSL handshake failed: <Hostname>: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)

Tags: mongodb, talend, mongodb-stitch, stitch

I have used the stitch data integration tool to transfer MongoDB data to stitch. But While running it
getting error as mention below

Guide me

```
2021-06-21 12:40:32,381Z   main - INFO Running tap-mongodb version 2.0.1 and target-stitch version 3.2.0
2021-06-21 12:40:33,237Z   main - INFO [smart-services] building smart service producer: topic( com.stitchdata.extractionJobStarted ), use_ssl( true )
2021-06-21 12:40:33,240Z   main - INFO [smart-services] building smart service producer: topic( com.stitchdata.extractionJobFinished ), use_ssl( true )
2021-06-21 12:40:33,240Z   main - INFO [smart-services] building smart service producer: topic( com.stitchdata.streamRecordCount ), use_ssl( true )
2021-06-21 12:40:34,246Z   main - INFO [smart-services] event successfully sent to kafka: com.stitchdata.extractionJobStarted [42] at offset None
2021-06-21 12:40:34,246Z   main - INFO Starting tap to discover schemas: tap-env/bin/tap-mongodb --config /tmp/tap_discover_config.json --discover
2021-06-21 12:41:04,706Z    tap - CRITICAL SSL handshake failed:  <Hostname>:27015: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap - Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -   File "tap-env/bin/tap-mongodb", line 33, in <module>
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -     sys.exit(load_entry_point('tap-mongodb==2.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'tap-mongodb')())
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tap_mongodb/__init__.py", line 394, in main
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -     raise exc
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tap_mongodb/__init__.py", line 391, in main
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -     main_impl()
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tap_mongodb/__init__.py", line 378, in main_impl
2021-06-21 12:41:04,708Z    tap -     client.server_info().get('version', 'unknown'))
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1658, in server_info
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     session=session)
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 655, in command
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     read_preference) as (sock_info, slave_ok):
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.2/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     return next(self.gen)
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1135, in _socket_for_reads
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     server = topology.select_server(read_preference)
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 226, in select_server
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     address))
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 184, in select_servers
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     selector, server_timeout, address)
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -   File "/code/orchestrator/tap-env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 200, in _select_servers_loop
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap -     self._error_message(selector))
2021-06-21 12:41:04,709Z    tap - pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: SSL handshake failed:  <Hostname>:27015: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)
2021-06-21 12:41:05,042Z   main - INFO Tap exited abnormally with status 1
2021-06-21 12:41:06,785Z   main - INFO [smart-services] event successfully sent to kafka: com.stitchdata.extractionJobFinished [4] at offset None
2021-06-21 12:41:06,786Z   main - INFO No tunnel subprocess to tear down
2021-06-21 12:41:06,786Z   main - INFO Exit status is: Discovery failed with code 1 and error message: "SSL handshake failed: <Hostname>: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:645)".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider setting the MongoClient parameter `tls=False` or the connction strng parameter`tls=false`.

Also see https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/tls.html